# The this.$store autocomplete from vuex in WebStorm doesn't work

Tags: autocomplete, vuex, webstorm

I'm writing an application using vue and vuex, and the `this.$store` autocompletion doesn't work in the component template. At the same time, the code works fine. Maybe I need to do something in the IDE settings? Here's an example where I use `this.$store`:

```
<div class="dropdown-item">
    <a
      class="button is-light"
      :class="{ 'is-hidden':$store.state.isAuth }"
      @click="openModal"
    >
        Войти
    </a>
</div>
```